# Game Coding for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to Javascript and for a class I'm taking we're supposed to finish up the code to make a game work. The game is of a truck and it's supposed to catch kiwis that are falling from the sky. The truck only moves left and right. There's a timer set at two minutes and when time is up, a pop up window will show saying how many kiwis were collected and it resets the count to zero. It should also indicate that pressing the button starts a new game. I tried to ask this question earlier but I couldn't figure out where I was formatting wrong. I resorted to using images instead. There are already built in functions/references such as the ones shown in the pictures as well as functions I need to finish:[image: Functions to finish][image: Functions to finish(2)][image: References][image: References(2)]

So far for my code I have:

```
kiwi_count = 0;
width = window.innerWidth;
height = window.innerHeight;
rate = console.log(kiwi_rate);

function render_frame(){
    if(is_down("right") == true){
        truck_move_right();
        truck_update_position();
    }
    else if(is_down("left") == true){
        truck_move_left();
        truck_update_position();
    }
    else if(is_down("b") == true){
        truck_brake();
        truck_update_position();
    }
    else{
        truck_coast();
        truck_update_position();
    }
    if(Math.random() * 10 <= rate){
        create_kiwi();
    }
}

function truck_move_right(){
    //code
}

function truck_move_left(){
    //code
}

function truck_coast(){
    //code
}

function truck_brake(){
    //code
}

function truck_update_position(){
    //code
}

function check_collision(kiwi){
    //code
}

function game_end(){
   //code
}
```

As you can see, I haven't gotten very far. I'm a little overwhelmed, especially since I've never set foot into the Javascript world before, so if anyone could help me at all, it'd be most appreciated!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure exactly what you're asking for. Is some of the code you've written so far not working as you expect?

Comment: This is perhaps a little open ended for Stack Overflow; you may not get the best answers. Do you have to use a particular library/framework? Phaser (http://phaser.io/) is pretty good to get started with.

Comment: @Paul S. I pretty positive what I have so far is correct in terms of recognizing whether the user is pressing the left,right, or b keys. What I'm not sure of is how to code the rest of the functions. I'm aware of all the built in functions given but how do I implement them? I need help finishing the empty functions in my code above.

Comment: @Donutttt No, there's not any one in particular that was mentioned.

Comment: Well, you have a skeleton to work from. Suppose we focus the question on the first empty function `truck_move_right()`. Some context is needed to provide help, like what kind of (code) object is the truck? Is it an HTML component? Do you already have HTML to share? This game needs some sort of board with pieces to move. Your javascript code needs to manipulate something, what is that something in your case?

Comment: @wintvelt Yes, there is HTML provided. I'm not able to include it above though since it's on the drive of someone at my school and you won't be able to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't do all your homework for you, but maybe this will help you out. Please notice I've left out important bits - see the `/* comments */`

```
function truck_move_right() {
    var velocity = get_truck_velocity();
    velocity += 5; // increment by 5
    if (velocity > 100) // 100 would be maximum velocity
        velocity = 100;
    set_truck_velocity(velocity);
}
// similar for `truck_move_left`

function truck_coast() {
    var velocity = get_truck_velocity(),
        delta = 2; // slowdown speed
    if (velocity > delta)
        velocity -= delta;
    else if (velocity < -delta)
        velocity += delta;
    else
        velocity = 0;
    set_truck_velocity(velocity);
}
// similar for `truck_break`

function truck_update_position() {
    var old_position = get_truck_left(),
        velocity = get_truck_velocity();
    if (/* would touch edge */) {
        velocity = -Math.round(velocity / 2); // turn around, go slower
        /* update truck velocity */
    }
    set_truck_left(old_position + velocity);
}

function check_collision(kiwi) {
    var kx = get_kiwi_x(kiwi),
        ky = get_kiwi_y(kiwi),
        tx = get_truck_left();
    if (/* kx close enough to tx */ && /* ky big enough to be caught*/) {
        // collision
        delete_kiwi(kiwi);
        // add score
        // return true
    }
    // return false;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help and if it's not too much to ask, would you mind explaining what you did for check_collision()?

Comment: It's still very much a stub, I did very little for that particular function

Comment: @Paul S. very nice of you to help OP out like this.

Comment: @wintvelt Well I didn't do all of it and if the code is just copy/pasted it wouldn't work as-is and I think it'd be obvious enough to any teacher looking over it

Comment: @PaulS. which is IMHO just what could be expected of SO Q&A: help OP make steps forward (which your answer surely does). So thumbs up from me ;)